# Concerns regarding UK Border Control and no job

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

So I am graduating from college this May, and to celebrate I'm going to Scotland to visit my girlfriend for nearly 2 months. I've been to the UK three times before, have never had any issues, and have always left when I said I was going to leave. But every time before then I've always had the obvious connection back home of college, and I've never stayed as long as I will this summer. As I'm going straight after school, I most likely won't have another job lined up and will therefore be unemployed. I do, however, have massive amounts of loans that I have to start paying back in November/December and I 100% plan on coming back here to the States and getting a job.

I have a return ticket, and plan to bring my printed itinerary, as well as bank statements. I was also going to bring my loan statements to show that I really do need to go back and get a job.

I'm just worried that the length of my stay and my lack of a job will make them suspicious of me, even though I would never, ever overstay. Is there anything else I could bring to show them that I do not plan on staying in the country? I'll be landing in Glasgow, if that helps at all.

Comment: Clarify your citizenship. This does affect the perceived overstay risk.

Comment: You could bring a job offer. Having student loans doesn't prove your intent to return to the US. After all, you could be trying to work illegally in the UK, or you could be skipping out on your loans... You could also bring some other reason to return to the US, but we don't know what that might be.

Comment: Don't play cat-and-mouse in your landing interview. They get truly annoyed with that.  Also, knowing your gender would be helpful in composing an answer.

Comment: @GayotFow I would presume that Rachel is female.

Comment: @phoog, agreed, but nationality/age/gender are huge influencing factors in their profiling; the more that can be positively nailed down the higher quality answer for the OP.

Comment: Just on a point of language, in British English, "girlfriend" means "female you're in a romantic relationship with", not just "female friend." So, if you just mean that you're visiting a female friend, definitely say "friend" and not "girlfriend". It would probably help if you edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Hi, I am a US citizen, female, age 22, who is in a romantic relationship with another female, so yes by girlfriend I do mean significant other. Like has been stated, I don't want to lie to the IO about who I'm going to see. Thanks for your help, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You are likely to arouse at least some suspicion.  You are:

1. A foreign citizen.
2. Without stated familial ties to another country.
3. Without leased or owned property elsewhere.
4. Coming to visit your lover for an extended period.
5. Without a job in any country at all.
6. Liable to repay a large sum of money if you return home.
7. Showing a pattern of multiple visits for non-business purposes.

It might be in your interest to not bring up the student loans unless asked.  They're a liability, not an asset, both financially and immigration-wise.  Claiming you want to return home so you can start paying money is not convincing.

The term "girlfriend" is ambiguous.  It might be in your interest to refer to her as simply your "friend" if you are not romantically involved.  This may not matter a lot, and in any case you should be honest if asked to clarify the relationship you have with this person.

Hopefully you have a substantial amount of money in your bank account(s).  One or two thousand bucks is not going to seem substantial given your circumstances.

If you do have an apartment lease back home, or are comfortable getting one (even if you sublet it whilst away), that might be helpful (you could bring a copy of the lease, though I don't think immigration would normally expect to see this).

Finally, as Michael Hampton said in a comment, you could get a job offer.  You don't even have to actually start that job when you return, if you decide it's not for you, but a signed and countersigned offer letter might be helpful.  Ideally for a job other than flipping burgers.  This piece is probably the hardest to get, but on the other hand that may make it more valuable from the immigration officer's point of view.

Comment: Saying "friend" when "girlfriend" represents the actual relationship (or vice versa) is something you should ***NEVER*** do. If the IO has some suspicion, they _will_ verify this, and if there is a discrepancy, you're looking at removal.

Comment: Hi, good to know about the loans. I do have a project/startup that I'm a part of (that I'm not currently getting paid for), should I state that, or does me not getting paid make it worse? I do have familial ties, all of my family lives here in the states. I do have a place to stay with my parents. And like Michael Hampton said, I'm not sure it's a fantastic idea to tell them she's my friend when I'm romantically involved with her. I really appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Good point, I've reworded that bit of my answer.  The main point I wanted to make was to not say "girlfriend" if the relationship is "a girl who is a friend."  But the OP has now clarified (in a comment) that it is a romantic relationship.